# Green spots on bullseye egg

Tags: eggs, onions, pan

I cooked some bulls eye eggs with some onion, and after cooking there was some green stain on the albumen, but not before cooking, therefore I wonder what it might be. I thought it could have come from the onion but just a hypothesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming clean pan, no green die/residue, transfering to the egg whites. In which case green spots would consider mold/bacterial contamination based on [this](https://eggsafety.org/what-color-variation-are-normal/), in which case "DO NOT EAT".

However if the whites are cloudy or overall green tint would be safe [caused by vitamin B2](https://extension.illinois.edu/eggs/res04-consumer.html). If you are getting fresh high quality eggs, this would be more likely.

Sorry I couldn't locate any good images to help out here, Green Eggs and Ham is really messing up the image search.